# a function about pc1 operation in DES

Tags: openssl, des

when I read the des source of "openssl "  . there is a comment that " 
do PC1 in 47 simple operations :-)
    * Thanks to John Fletcher (john_fletcher@lccmail.ocf.llnl.gov)
    * for the inspiration. :-)
"

```
PERM_OP (d,c,t,4,0x0f0f0f0fL);
HPERM_OP(c,t,-2,0xcccc0000L);/
HPERM_OP(d,t,-2,0xcccc0000L);/
PERM_OP (d,c,t,1,0x55555555L);
PERM_OP (c,d,t,8,0x00ff00ffL);
PERM_OP (d,c,t,1,0x55555555L);
```

it could reduce 56 operation to 47 .

Could anyone tell me theory of this . ?

And  the array static const DES_LONG des_skb[8][64]={

it isn't define  in arithmetic statement

why the openssl optimize it~~~?